# Directory.GetFiles() returning deleted/phantom file over network

Tags: c#, getfiles

I have a process, completely separate from the process calling `GetFiles()`, that takes the file `Big.xml` and breaks it down into `little_1.xml`, `little_2.xml`... etc.

Once it has finished a separate app gets the files:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dir, *.xml);
```

In the 'files' list is the `Big.xml` file as well as all the `little_x.xml` files.

Even `File.Exists("Big.xml")` returns `true`, it doesn't error until opening `Big.xml` is attempted.

Is this likely to be a network issue, `Directory.GetFiles()` is static so presumably nothing is cached here, the code all looks good - has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Erm, that's rather clumsy isn't it?  Use GetFiles(dir, "little*.xml") instead.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not as simple as that, Hans. We do have a work around but it's the fact it isn't working when it should that is bugging me.

Comment: I would imagine it is running so fast that you can't even see it happen. Can you have Big.xml in an input directory, and the litte_x.xml in a separate output directory - then have your additional process parse the output directory only?

Comment: That, @AutomationNation, is similar to our current work around, however, it's not down to fast processing as it happens even with forced delays. This is what prompted me to post here in an attempt to satisfy my curiosity... Think I'll just have to let sleeping dogs lie though.

Comment: i'm having the same problem, did you find a fix?